# How to go from a view to another view controller (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a table view in a view controller (view based application), once a user selects one of the cells it should load another view.. I tried the navigation controller thing but that resulted in a huge failure along with 5-6 hours wasted (it crashes when I try to pushViewController onto the nav. controller). Is there anyway to move from one view controller to the other? Keeping in mind I need to send over the selected cell (a string)

Thanks

Edit:For those curious, I created another project as a navigation based application. Everything is working now.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: If you are faced with a crash, it's usually far, far easier and results in a far, far better result if you concentrate on fixing the crash rather than giving up and trying to do something different.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement the `UITableView` delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndex`. Here's an example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        [detailViewController setData:[tableViewData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];     
        [detailViewController release];
}
```

In your DetailViewController.m file, once you're finished with it, simply use

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to pop it off the stack.

Comment: that's exactly what I did previously.. it crashes with sigabrt when calling pushviewcontroller :(

Comment: Have you created a navigationController at this point? If not, then you must do that first. It would probably help if you edit your question to include the code that you have, then we can see how to edit that to get it right.

Comment: Yes I did.. I recreated it again and now pushViewController does not work at all